# C# print 2D-array in order. Please help!

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I got a 2-dimentional array containing boolean values written in C#.
The cols and rows of the array are to be determined by the user upon creation of the array.
I then want to print out the array and it´s containing values onto the console in order.

For example like this, how is this done in C#?

ROWS - COLS - VALUE

---

1 - A - True

1 - B - True

1 - C - True

1 - D - True

---

2 - A - True

2 - B - False

2 - C - False

2 - D - True

---

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for aside from a simple nested loop here. Can you show what the array itself would look like?

Comment: No, this is no homework, I am trying to learn C# because my boss wants our firm to offer C# to our customers. Stupid if you ask me.

Comment: What do you mean by "The cols and rows of the array are to be determined by the user"? Can you clarify?

Comment: That the customer can just create the size of the array by them selfs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int row = 0; row < array.Length; row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");

    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].Length; col++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", row + 1, 'A' + col, array[row][col]);
    }
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's is another approach and a complete example. I like working with Lambda but making the first foreach to a lambda aswell wouldn't be very pretty.

```
var array = new[]
                {
                    new [] { true, false, true, true, false },
                    new [] { false, false, true, false, false },
                    new [] { true, true , true, true, true}
                };

var rowId = 1;
var colId = 0;

foreach (var row in array)
{
    row.ToList().ForEach(value => Console.WriteLine(
         string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", rowId, (char)('A' + colId++), value)));

    rowId += 1;

    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");
}
```

Will output the following:

```
1 - A - True
1 - B - False
1 - C - True
1 - D - True
1 - E - False
--------------------------
2 - A - False
2 - B - False
2 - C - True
2 - D - False
2 - E - False
--------------------------
3 - A - True
3 - B - True
3 - C - True
3 - D - True
3 - E - True
--------------------------
```

Comment: Ha I don't think the OP will handle lambdas if they can't handle multidimensionals (or even work out a Google reference on it).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of this assignment is to learn it yourself. Put some code up of what you've tried first. I really don't think anyone should be answering these kinds of questions unless they have some code already and can't work out where they're going wrong.

Comment: No, this is no homework, I am trying to learn C# because my boss wants our firm to offer C# to our customers. Stupid if you ask me.

Comment: Presumably you know another language already if you're being asked this?

Comment: And if you don't, you're not going to gain the mental model of a multidimensional array by just asking for code that prints a particular format.

Comment: Yeah, I know but my boss is breathing down my neck. We need to be ready by july because one of our better customers are starting to request more programming services from us. I really just need to get ahead of this "deadline". Thanks for all help!

Comment: If you need to learn a new language completely from scratch it's already too late.

Comment: Mm, I know, but tell that to my boss... :)

Comment: @Phil It's too late if he doesn't know multi-dimensional arrays anyway. Patching a new language is doable but learning language fundamentals isn't going to happen in less than 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Cell[] rows in cells) {
    foreach (Cell c in rows) {
        // print id, c.letter, c.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that doesn't work in C# for some reason. (Edit: of course it does, just not for staggered arrays (bool[,] arr)